# Как прикрепить синий div к красному?

Tags: html5, css

Есть 2 div - красный и синий.

http://webformyself.com/forum/uploads/monthly_09_2014/post-3574-0-70259000-1409929764_thumb.png

Синий нужно прикрепить к красному внизу так, чтобы если перемещается красный, то синий всегда прикреплен к нему внизу.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Можно и просто расположить их друг после друга, всё зависит от того, где это будет применяться

http://jsfiddle.net/k1hoy6vq/

```js
setInterval(function(){
    var newX,newY;
    newX = Math.random()*300;
    newY = Math.random()*300;
    $('#movable').animate({top:newY,left:newX},700);
},1000);
```

```css
.part{
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
.red{
    height: 60px;
    background: #f00;
}
.blue{
    height: 40px;
    background: #00f;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="movable" class="red part">
    ABC
    <div class="blue part">
       DFG 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы не сохранили свой вариант. =/

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое - запихнуть синий внутрь красного, поставить overflow и сместить синий при помощи top вниз.

http://jsfiddle.net/k1hoy6vq/

Comment: Интересно, но нужен вариант без запихивания.

Comment: Тогда поточнее опишите задачку. Поправьте фиддл под конкретные условия и положите сюда ссылку.
Просто как вариант можно запихнуть прямо яваскриптом.